# Mongoose - When returning all items from a collection (with no search param) the returned items from the collection do not contain their mongo _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a bit of an issue with Mongoose/MongoDB this afternoon. I have a situation where I need to return all items from a collection, and doing so means that I do not pass in any search params to `mongoose.find()`.

This is the controller that handles the get all request:

```
exports.get_all_posts = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { params } = req;
  const { sortby } = params;

  //Sortby param takes two arguments for now: most_recent, oldest
  try {
    const getAllPosts = await BlogPost.find({}, { _id: 0 });

    console.log(getAllPosts);

    if (!getAllPosts) throw new Error('Could not get blog posts.');

    res.json({
      posts: date_.sort(getAllPosts, sortby)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

This is particularly where I think the issue is coming from:

```
const getAllPosts = await BlogPost.find({}, { _id: 0 });
```

I am passing an empty search parameter and then removing the `_id` so that it doesn't throw an error telling me that I need to provide the `_id`.

However I still need to be able to pull in all of the posts. My items from this collection return as normal, just without their `_id`'s.

Here is my model for the blog posts:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BlogPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    required: false
  },
  post_body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tags: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  ],
  featuredImage: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  draft: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);
```

One thing to note is that I have not defined an `_id`. Mongoose automatically adds in the `_id` field before saving a schema, so I think it is okay without it, as it has been in the past.

Thanks in advance for reading and any input!

Comment: `{ _id: 0 }` is the projection telling the mongod to not return the `_id` field.  There shouldn't be any error associated with not providing a projection, so `const getAllPosts = await BlogPost.find({});` should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you @Joe. This was it, I appreciate the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282634/joe) has commented, `{ _id: 0 }` as the second parameter is making your query not return the `_id` field.

Also as he said, there should be no problem whatsoever with using `find({})`.

Since other than what has already been stated, I couldn't figure out any mistake in the code snippets you provided, I guess this error could be coming from somewhere else in your project.

Comment: Changing the find() query worked no problem. Weird, because when I initially just used find({}), it returned an error saying the _id was invalid. That made me think that I needed to omit the ID in the find() options. I might of been doing something else wrong, and caused the initial error I described. It fixed itself when I removed the _id from the find() function, so I went with it not knowing the _id would of be omitted from the returned results.

Comment: @maison.m sounds like some sort of Heisenbug, but glad to see that everything worked out fine in the end, and you fixed your problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.get_all_posts = async (req, res, next) => { const { params } = req; const { sortby } = params;
 try { const getAllPosts = await BlogPost.find({}); console.log(getAllPosts); if (!getAllPosts) throw new Error('Could not get blog posts.'); res.json({ posts: date_.sort(getAllPosts, sortby) }); } catch (error) { next(error); } };
```

no need to {_id:0} in the **find()** method because this method retrieve all the documents in the db collection

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue.